# Srtruts2 Login/Logout not working for back button

Tags: struts2

struts.xml

```
<action name="firstLogin" class="com.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">loginError.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="logout" class="com.action.LoginAction" method="logout">
        <result name="success">Index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<s:form action="firstLogin" method="post">
<s:textfield name="adminId" label="Admin ID"></s:textfield>
<s:password name="adminPassword" label="Password" />
<s:submit value="LOGIN" />
</s:form>
```

LoginAction.jsp

```
package com.action;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.dao.DBOperationsDao;


public class LoginAction implements SessionAware {
//LoginModel modelObj=new LoginModel(); 
private String adminId;
private String adminPassword;
SessionMap<String,String> sessionMap;



public void setAdminId(String adminId) {
    this.adminId = adminId;
    System.out.println("setter 1...............");

}

public String getAdminId() {
    return adminId;
}
public void setAdminPassword(String adminPassword) {
    this.adminPassword = adminPassword;
    System.out.println("setter 2...............");
}
public String getAdminPassword() {
    return adminPassword;
}

public String execute() throws Exception{
    int i=DBOperationsDao.adminAuth(this);

    if(i>0){
        return "success";
    }
    else{
        return "error";
    }

}

public void setSession(Map map){
    sessionMap =(SessionMap)map;
    sessionMap.put("login", "true");
    System.out.println("session value after set"+sessionMap.get("login"));
}

public SessionMap<String, String> getSessionMap() {
    return sessionMap;
}

public String logout(){
    sessionMap.invalidate();
    System.out.println("session value after              invalidate"+sessionMap.get("login"));
    return "success";
}

}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<s:if test="%{#session['login']}">

<s:property value="%{#session['login']}"/>

<h3>Hello Admin </h3>
<a href="addUser.jsp">Add User</a> | <a href="search.jsp">Search User</a>|<a   href="logout">Logout</a>

</s:if>
<s:else>
<jsp:forward page="Index.jsp" />
</s:else>
```

question: logout is working fine, and if i hit the url also its redirecting to login page as i excepted but once after i logged out i can get the welcome page by clicking on back button in the browser. this shouldn't happens to me.. pls help me on this

Comment: A session is always created, you need to check (in each method of each Action, or in an Interceptor) if a particular object is in the sessionMap. When you login, put that object in the map, when you logout, remove it. During every operation, check if it's there.

Comment: Why this shouldn't happen, as for me it's valid to have a browser caches pages you have to return without intervention of the server.

Comment: @AndreaLigios , Thanks for your response, I have only one controller over here and in the am having only one session object that also am making invalid.

Answer (score 0):

For that You have to clear the browser cache in logout page and the page used before you click logout Or its better to that in every page.

Add The code below in start of every page inside jsp scriplet.

```
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
```

Comment: @Prakash.Thanks for the response, After log out and click on back button i will get confirm form resubmission, from their if i go for refreshing the page again its going to welcome page.Sorry this piece of code couldn't give me a solution.

Comment: @user3364329 it's ok.actually what are you excepting to happen when you click the back button after logging out.pls explain it clear..